# Masking a pandas DataFrame with a numpy array vs DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to use a 2D boolean mask to selectively alter some cells in a `pandas` `DataFrame`.  I noticed that I *cannot* use a `numpy` array (successfully) as the mask, but I *can* use a `DataFrame`.  More frustrating, however, is that I *don't get an error with the `numpy` approach*.

For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4], 
                   'B':[10,20,30,40]})

mask_np = np.array([[True,True],
                    [False,False],
                    [True,False],
                    [False,True]])

mask_pd = pd.DataFrame(mask_np, columns=['A','B'])
```

I would think either mask would return the values from `df` wherever the mask was `True`.  But instead, `df[mask_np]` produces

```
   A   B
0  1  10
0  1  10
2  3  30
3  4  40
```

which is not what I expect, nor can I explain.  On the other hand,  `df[mask_pd]` produces

```
     A     B
0  1.0  10.0
1  NaN   NaN
2  3.0   NaN
3  NaN  40.0
```

which is what I expect and want.

Why can't I use the `numpy` mask? My internet search turned up nothing relevant.  Any explanation behind this difference would be greatly appreciated!

[`pandas` version 0.20.3; Python 3.6.3]

Answer (score 3):

The source code suggests why. The `__getitem__` method, for which `[]` is syntactic sugar, checks specifically for indexing via a dataframe:

```
elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
    return self._getitem_frame(key)
```

The `_getitem_frame` method called then returns [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) if the dataframe is of Boolean type:

```
def _getitem_frame(self, key):
    if key.values.size and not is_bool_dtype(key.values):
        raise ValueError('Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only')
    return self.where(key)
```

The route taken for NumPy arrays, `_getitem_array`, is different and more convoluted. For some reason, the code is designed to treat NumPy / Pandas inputs differently, rather than to ensure consistency for the same *data types*.

---

Regular Boolean indexing with a Pandas dataframe is usually applied along an axis, i.e. by rows / axis 0 via `df.loc[mask, :]` or columns / axis 1 via `df.loc[:, mask]`.

Note you can, and probably should, access [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) directly for clarity:

```
res = df.where(mask_np)

print(res)

     A     B
0  1.0  10.0
1  NaN   NaN
2  3.0   NaN
3  NaN  40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Write down the row indices of the `True`'s in your `mask_np`: row `0`, row `0`, row `2`, row `3`. Select the rows with the same indices in `df` and concatenate them. That's how `df[mask_np]` is produced.

This is probably a Pandas bug, since it's assumed in the source code that the array used for indexing is 1-dimensional.

---

Looking at the source code (Pandas 0.23.4),

```
df[mask_np]
```

is equivalent to

```
df._getitem_bool_array(mask_np)
```

is equivalent to

```
indexer = mask_np.nonzero()[0]
df._take(indexer, axis=0)
```

with the following evaluation:

```
>>> mask_np.nonzero()
(array([0, 0, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

This tuple of arrays represents indices of nonzero elements along the dimensions of the array. In this case, the elements of first array in the tuple (eventually used in `df._take`) are 'row' indices  of `True`'s in `mask_df`.

The first array is used to `take` along the index, so you get rows `0, 0, 2, 3` of `df` in return.