# Selecting dataframe with 2D boolean mask created by isnull()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This is my DataFrame:

```
area = pd.Series({'California': 423967, 'Texas': 695662,'New York': 141297, 'Florida': None, 'Illinois': 149995})
pop = pd.Series({'California': 38332521, 'Texas': None,'New York': 19651127, 'Florida': 19552860, 'Illinois': 12882135})
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'area':area, 'pop':pop})
data1

area    pop
California  423967.0    38332521.0
Texas   695662.0    NaN
New York    141297.0    19651127.0
Florida NaN 19552860.0
Illinois    149995.0    12882135.0
```

Then I check for null using isnull() and it returns a boolean array, which when on using as mask, gives this output:

```
data1[data1.isnull()]

area    pop
California  NaN NaN
Texas   NaN NaN
New York    NaN NaN
Florida NaN NaN
Illinois    NaN NaN
```

I don't understand how it is working in this case. I embarrassed myself in class when I tried to extend the idea that it would've worked the same as using Series.notnull() as mask, but it was not even something deducible. I expected it to work like opposite of dropna().

Edit: Another caveat is that, when doing a similar mask on numpy array, I get all elements in a 1d array, but in pandas the same behavior is not replicated. I can think of one reason for that as losing information about columns and index, but is that the real reason it doesn't work like numpy?

Answer (score 0):

To view the rows containing NaN values you can collapse the columns into an linear array for indexing by applying your logic explicitly:

```
# the any() operator returns True if the row contains a True somewhere
has_na = [any(row) for row in data1.isna().values]

print(data1[has_na])
```

which prints

```
             area         pop
Texas    695662.0         NaN
Florida       NaN  19552860.0
```

Comment: Okay, but why does it give all nans? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123388/masking-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-numpy-array-vs-dataframe) question the output should have been nan only where the mask is false, not all of them.